# Couldn't Kill Bluetooth Daemon

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-gnome

I couldn't kill Bluetooth daemon in Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried below steps by seeing suggestions in internet.

1. ```
   rfkill unblock Bluetooth
   ```
2. ```
   sudo service Bluetooth stop
   ```
3. ```
   killall -9 bluetoothd
   ```

But still process is there even though if I kill it.

Comment: did you try to find the process with `ps` or `top` ? probably your process isn't start at all ...

Comment: Yes, I could find the process using ps. It's always running

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `systemctl disable bluetooth.service` will work?  Do you actually have a bluetooth device?

Answer (score -1):

In order to kill easily your process, get his PID with `ps`

and use the folliwing command : 
`kill -9 <PID>` where PID is the PID of your process (here, PID of bluetoothd)

Comment: Yes, I have tried killing using kill -9 PID , but same result again.. it's not at all killing bluetoohd